# Cocos2d - scheduled selector never called

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

For some reason one of the methods I'm scheduling isn't getting called.

The class's parent's parent inherits from CCNode. The class's parent has a method called resetCoolDown like this:

```
- (void) resetCoolDown:(ccTime)dt {
    _onCoolDown = false;
}
```

I schedule like this:

```
[self scheduleOnce:@selector(resetCoolDown:) delay:1];
```

There are no issues scheduling the selector, but for some reason `resetCoolDown` is never called.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: If the class instance you schedule the selector in is a subclass of the class that implements the resetCoolDown method it should work - as long as  said class instance is still around (ie added as child). Perhaps you are confusing parent (a node's parent property) with superclass (oop inheritance)? Though that should give an undeclared selector warning.

Comment: Even if I add the method to the class where I'm scheduling the selector, it still never gets called. I tried using an action sequence with CCCallBack and still nothing...

Comment: then that node isn't in the node hierarchy? Check if it deallocates.

Comment: also if you override onEnter and didn't call super onEnter scheduling may stop working

Comment: If I try to schedule it again I get this in the log: CCScheduler#scheduleSelector. Selector already scheduled. Updating interval from: 0.0000 to 0.0000